# Is there mass i.e a physical bottom to a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-hole, space-time, space

All matter has a gravitational pull, a ball, a rock, a planet and a star - the bigger the matter the more it affects the space fabric around it thus having a greater gravitational pull.

I see black holes in the same kind of concept - matter that warps the space fabric/time around it - however as we can physically see a ball, a rock, a planet and a star I fail to visualize what would be the matter that continues a black hole to operate because we cannot see any physical element to it.

**EXAMPLE**
[image]

A black hole is cause when a star implodes on itself and crushes its self to an extent that gravity has such an effect on space time that we know of nothing that produce such a force.

What I would like to know is:

1: Is there a known "bottom" of a black hole? If so, what happens to all of the matter it swallows? surely it would be impossible to crush something so small that it physically no longer exists - where would it go then?

2: How small does the core of a collapsed star crush itself into? i.e the size of an atom or smaller?

Comment: Don't use that diagram, it's horribly misleading.